# How do you change the time before text resets in Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In windows explorer if you start to type it will select an item that starts with your text. how do you lower the time before the text resets and you can look for the next file.

Files

- a
- b
- ac
- aa

If I type "a",
"a" will be selected.
If I wait before hitting "a" again, "ac" will be selected instead of "aa" because the search reset. How do I change the time before it resets?
I hope this is clear. Ask me to reword this if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's exactly what you're asking, but perhaps a different way would work for you:

You can hit `Esc` to reset the search/find behavior. So using your sample directory, if you type "a", it will select "a". Then if you hit `Esc`, you can type a different search term (so you could then type "ac" and get "ac" selected).

Like I said, it's not exactly what you asked. But maybe it's helpful?

Comment: That is helpful, I am sure there is some kind of registry tweak or something that can do what I am looking for